# How to auto update file path class attribute on change without pressing enter?

Tags: python

I am coding an addon that needs the user to select a file path in the properties. When selecting a file path, the class attribute for the file path does not update. It will only update if the string is manually typed and 'enter' is pressed at the end. How can I force it to update the attribute after selecting the file path without pressing enter?

The file path is created fully in a panel class and uses no operators.

Comment: Have you tried creating a callback function and using it as the update argument for your [StringProperty](/home/jake/blender/addons/Blender3mfFormat-1.0.1/io_mesh_3mf)? Something like `def update_prop(self, context): setattr(self, 'filepath', filepath_string)`. Just a shot in the dark really.

Comment: Also have you tried making sure the subtype of your StringProperty is set to 'FILE_PATH', that might change it's behavior in the browser.